# Liked Open Graph Protocol (OGP) enabled page/URL does not appear in facebook profile's interest section, Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Why liked Open Graph Protocol (OGP) enabled page/URL does not appear in facebook profile's interest section.
where as, it is working perfectly fine using Facebook Lint [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug].

Lots of posts on this, but did not find right answer
Question snippet is: when you like my page it will be flow in your *activity feeds* but not appearing in any of **likes and interest** section on your *'info'* page.

where as, imdb.com doing this correctly, please help me.
regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, I think. When you "like" IMDB, you are in fact liking the facebook page of IMDB. Then it's showing up in your profile. You are not liking IMDB.com but their facebook page. So you should create a facebook page and put a box on your website so when people like this box they will in fact like your facebook page ..

You can find this box here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. you get me wrong, 
1. just click on 'like' button on this page http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
2. check whether it is flowing in your *activity feeds*. it will be.
3. now check your **info** tab-> likes and interests section (it will be there as a facebook page where as URL is of site's URL [http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/])

I want same thing to do.

Comment: @AarushiKhanna yes maybe a too quick response it seems ... did you check that you have exactly all the same og meta tags as in the imdb page ?

Comment: yes off course, but if any major one I am missing then please share with me.